# How to get my script works- Google Sheets onEdit script

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to auto-sort by two columns in the range A2:E every time a new line adds to the sheets.

I used this code:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:E"); 
  range.sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}, {column: 4, ascending: true}]); 
}
```

and it works. just one problem
if i got the same "name" (column 1) twice but in a diffrent hour (column 4)
it's first sort it by the name.
what i am trying to do is to devided to groups. that after it's sort it by the column it will sort this "group" by the hour (column 4)

Comment: Your question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following script:

```
function sortR(e) {
  var t = e.changeType;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:E"); 
  if(t == "INSERT_ROW")
  {
    range.sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}, {column: 4, ascending: true}]); 
  }
}
```

Your script was working fine, however your trigger was recognizing any changes made to the sheet because you had an `onChange` trigger, but if you want to do it more specific you need to use an `onChange` trigger which is installable.

When testing the script you need to make sure you add the trigger to the triggers section in the Google Apps Script UI.

#### Trigger settings:

[image]

#### References:

- [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers)
- [onChange trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)